# Jenkins pipeline on master stuck when slave reboots

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins linux master and windows 7 slave that is using java webstart (JNLP: agent.jar) in user session (started from windows task scheduler). Problem is that I have to reboot slave (also hibernate, sleep etc.) during test run, and after slave reboots pipeline on master is stuck forever. I.e. Slave reconnects and is visible as online, but in job console i can only see error from disconnection and circle animation:

```
Cannot contact CORNER5-W7: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@4d8aa8ce:CORNER5-W7": Remote call on CORNER5-W7 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
```

How can I make it resume pipeline after slave reconnects? I thought it was jenkins feature to auto-detect slave is back online and to resume work ?

[image: gif showing jenkins console]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use JNLP agents which would work seamlessly for your use case. you create agent.jar from master and run it on slave machine in the background or as a windows service. As the connection is initiated from agent --> master, slave will keep reconnecting to the master if master is down and vice-versa.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using - (I've fixed my question so it is obvious now), and slave is reconnected to master after reboot without problems (i.e. it is seen as "online" on master) the problem is that pipeline on master is stuck on connection loss, and waiting forever, not restarting and not failing

Comment: If your pipeline is getting stuck while Agent/Master is down, you could add a timeout in your pipeline so that if its running for more than a certain minutes/hours , it should fail rather than stuck for a lifetime.

Comment: Problem is - I don't want it to fail (as reboot is part of installation and testing), and after few seconds connection is restored (node is on line) but pipeline won't resume